# Cannot search multiselect after modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have 2 multi selects in a page, and I need to transfer some of the option in first into second, while mantaining the search capabilities.

The problem is, that when I use the search input, it restores the selects to their original options...

Here is the jquery search function:

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function() {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);

        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
            var search = $.trim($(this).val());
            var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                    $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Here is the js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/C2XXR/ !

**I believe the problem lies in the options variable, but have no idea on how to solve it **

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/C2XXR/2/

I have updated the code for right and left transfer. You have to change the option array itself got the filter, adding them in the dom will not work. In the changed code one issue is once we add from right to left or left to right it is getting added in the last position of the target select.

Please check and let me know if this is what you want.

Below is the main changed function. Later you can create a common function i suppose. Code can be optimized more.

```
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {

        var selected = $(this).parent().prev('select');
        var target = $(this).parent().next('select');

        target.find('option[value="999"]').remove()

        var options = selected.data('options');      
        var selectedVal = selected.find('option:selected').val()    

        var tempOption = [];
        $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.value != selectedVal) {
                   tempOption.push(option);
                }
            });

        var targetOptions = target.data('options'); 
        targetOptions.push({value: selected.find('option:selected').val(), text:   selected.find('option:selected').text()});        
         target.data('options', targetOptions);

        selected.find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
        selected.data('options', tempOption);
    });

    $('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {

        var selected = $(this).parent().next('select');
        var target = $(this).parent().prev('select');

        var options = selected.data('options');      
        var selectedVal = selected.find('option:selected').val()    

        var tempOption = [];
        $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.value != selectedVal) {
                   tempOption.push(option);
                }
            });
        if( tempOption.length == 0 )
        {
            // add 999 here
        }

        var targetOptions = target.data('options'); 
        targetOptions.push({value: selected.find('option:selected').val(), text:   selected.find('option:selected').text()});        

         target.data('options', targetOptions);


        selected.find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');;
        selected.data('options', tempOption);
    });
```

Comment: There is a problem though, with the right select box. All the options stack up, instead of showing one at a time

Comment: Welcome. Please dont forget the bounty. My first bounty in Stackoverflow. Thanks !!

Comment: No problem, I cannot give bounty right away but in 24 hours, stackoverflow rules..Will you please help me with the right select box too? The left one works great! But the right one doesnt at all :( Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Sorry dont know about that. Please let me know what issue you see there?

Comment: edit: It works well when searching...but maybe the users wont always search...when adding manually, it does not work! Thanks again!

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean by "when adding manually". I might be missing any point.

Comment: found the issue, but don't know how to solve it..if you add multiple countries (drag and drop on the select), and then move it to the right select, it will search in an array of names...so, **you need to select multiple countries BEFORE moving them...** THANKS A LOOOT! Saved my day! as I do not know jquery well..

Comment: The point is to update the options array properly. Any time you remove or add ay element from left to right or vice versa just remember to update the options array and then reassign it to the select data. Just FYI :) Ohh you are also adding drag drop support. :)

Comment: nono, you understand wrong. in a multiple select, you can select multiple countries before clicking the left button. if you do this, then it wont move each country individually, but as a group

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that after you click `btnRight` or `btnLeft` your collection of options for each `select` is not updated, so try after click on each button to call your `filterByText` as the  following :

```
  $('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().next('select').find('option[value="999"]').remove()
        $(this).parent().prev('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
        $('#canselect_code').filterByText($('#textbox'), true);
        $('#isselect_code').filterByText($('#textbox1'), true)

    });

    $('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {

        $(this).parent().next('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');
         $('#canselect_code').filterByText($('#textbox'), true);
         $('#isselect_code').filterByText($('#textbox1'), true)
 });
```

Comment: this wont work, as the options will be updated with an empty array